# What kind of hook can I use if I want to change my custom price on Woocommerce bulk edit page?

Tags: hook-woocommerce

I created custom price for WC_Product, put them into WC Bulk Edit Page and want to save changed values to disk.

I have seen  class WC_Admin_Post_Types (woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php) and found there some kind of hooks.

I tried to hook `woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', but this trigger does not work (or I did something wrong there).

I did find examples in WWW, but then I shall create and use  wp_ajax_{something} and 20-30 lines JS code.

May be exists another way for this - my custom price needs all the same as native WC price - where can I see how they are handled and save?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect my custom function to hook `woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save': this hook run if any of native Bulk Edit Fields will be filled, but I filled  my custom field only. All should be fine. Thanks if you read this).